# Cheerio & Gifv issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am attempting to scrape a Reddit, to obtain gifs. I am limiting the scraping to just take imgur, but there is a variance in the urls, some are .gif and most are .gifv.

My solution is to delete the v from gifv as the gifs, will still work. But when attempting to do so I have failed.

I tried to turn what cheerio spits out,

```
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
url.toString();
```

and then later edit it, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: More improvements to this question is needed,as where exactly are you going wrong,it is better to put your complete code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
url= url.slice(0, -1);
```

Output:

```
var url= "http://i.imgur.com/zvATqgs.gifv"
url.slice(0, -1);
"http://i.imgur.com/zvATqgs.gif"
```

Comment: Thanks, when i tried slicing my line was just,
url.slice I didnt set it equal thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ? You want to get the URL of the link element ?

If yes, your code should be working...

Can you create a JSFiddle with your HTML + JS code and post it here please ?